# Best way to generate Base64String for complex template Image

Tags: android, html, css, xamarin.android

Can I know what is the best approach to form complex tables like shown below. Is it possible to use Webview with CSS as a source instead of html? Any other suggestions for this? I want to form the table and bind data to it and send the formed table using base64 image string in the payload. I use xamarin android for my app.

[Image Table with slant border]:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN871.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can load the image file into a Bitmap (which works with all image-formatss supported by android) and encode the Bitmap byte-Array with base64.

```
int IMG_QUALITY_CONVERSIOM_FOR_NON_LOSSLESS_FORMATS = 60; // choose between 0 and 100

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(/*photoPath*/imageFile.getPath(), options);
// you can also scale the image here if needed
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] imageBytes = null;
try{
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, IMG_QUALITY_CONVERSIOM_FOR_NON_LOSSLESS_FORMATS, stream);
    imageBytes = stream.toByteArray();
}finally{
    bitmap.recycle();
    stream.close();
}

if(imageBytes!=null){
    String bytesB64 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
else{...}
```

One additional hint: you can read ANY image file that is supported by android this way, however if you pass the base64 or bitmap onto a website use `"image/png"` as mimetype!

Comment: Why would you use an intermediate bitmap where you can  base64 encode the image file itself? Strange approach.